# What happens to those saved during the millennial reign that die? (Premillennialist perspective)

Tags: eschatology, death, premillennialism

From what I understand of premillenial eschatology, during the millennial reign, [people who survived the tribulation](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024:13&version=KJV) will have their [longevity returned like before the flood, but they will still die.](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2065:20&version=KJV) What happens to those that die, but are saved? [Jesus is already on earth with the saints](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Zechariah%2014:5&version=KJV), the people saved before the tribulation; but what about those saved after? Would they just get their glorified bodies immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I understand it. The people who have become believers during the Millennium Kingdom won't die! Think about it. We know from Scripture that the people who make up the population during this time are those who were martyred during the Tribulation and came back to life to reign with Christ, and those who didn't take the mark of the beast, instead choosing to believe and accept Christ and survived the Tribulation.
The other inhabitants are the Saints-the dead in Christ who were resurrected and those raptured before the Tribulation. They will also rule and reign with Christ.
The people who are still in fleshly bodies will be like as in Noah's day, eating and drinking, working and playing, marrying and having children. Everyone will live long, long lives. The age of accountability will be extended to a hundred years! There will be no babies or children that die. All who are born during that time will have to choose Jesus (be saved) just as before the Millennium. Those who don't accept Christ will be cursed. If they die during the Millennium, they will go to Hades to await the final judgment. If they remain alive until the thousand years over ended, then they will have an opportunity to accept Christ or participate in the last rebellion when Satan will be loosed for a time to deceive the nations. There will be absolutely no fence sitting at this time. After the thousand years are ended, the rest of the dead will come back to life and be judged. Read Rev. 21 for what happens next!

Comment: Hmm, I never thought of the possibility of only unsaved dying. That's an interesting thought. People from Noah's day still died though. Methuselah still died at 969, which is less than 1,000 years.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: I realize this is a but late, but I recently had a teacher in my Revelation class say he believes the same, so it seems likely to me as he definitely knows his stuff.

Comment: I doubt thus theory...the people eating and drinking in thee days of Noah were the wicked, not the saved!

Answer (score 3):

The passage you link to is [Isaiah 65:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2065:20&version=NIV1984):

> Never again will there be in it an infant who lives but a few days, or an old man who does not live out his years; he who dies at a hundred will be thought a mere youth; he who fails to reach a hundred will be considered accursed.

Your assumption is that this is referring to Christians. However, we know that during the Millenium there will be Christians and non-Christians (either those that come out of the Tribulation or perhaps people born during these 1000 years):

> [Revelation 20:7-8](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2020:7-8&version=NIV1984)
>
> When the thousand years are over, Satan will be released from his prison and will go out to deceive the nations in the four corners of the earth—Gog and Magog—to gather them for battle. In number they are like the sand on the seashore.

So my understanding is that Christians will all have their resurrected, immortal bodies during the Millenium, and non-Christians will not.

Unfortunately, this theory does not address what happens to people who *become* Christians during this time!

Answer (score 1):

According to Rev.20:14 and Rev.21:1-5, death is cast into the lake of fire after the millennial and the final judgement is over and therefore, the sting of death and the victory of the grave are no more. Therefore all the survivors of the great tribulation that shall live on to the millennial reign of Jesus Christ with their mortal bodies and all the children born during the period will still be subjected to death until after the final judgement. after the final judgement, no one will die again. So i believe, eventhough it is not stated categorically in the those passages, that those with mortal bodies will then be automatically transformed by the Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 1):

“Here's how I understand it.” (Yes, Excellente position!! Please, I ask you permission to use your notes and I will try to explain how I  understand this question. OK?)

Who will be there for the millennium, the 1000-year reign of Christ and won't die?
1. Who people with new bodies, glorified bodies, transformed and resurrected bodies (Hebrews 12:22-24; Rev 21:10 showed us the holy city, Jerusalem, coming down out of Heaven from God. And its population is formed by: Lord Jesus with his angels;  all Saints resurrected from dead of all eras until end of tribulation and those that will be changed and resurrected from Church 
1 Corinthians 15:51).

2. “The people who are still in fleshly bodies and  will be like as in Noah's day, eating and drinking, working and playing, marrying and having children...”

— And have become believers during the tribulation and survived (And  in the Judgment of Nations will be the sheep in Matthew 25:31-33)
"But when the Son of Man comes in His glory, and all the angels with Him, then He will sit on His glorious throne. 32 All the nations will be gathered before Him; and He will separate them from one another, as the shepherd separates the sheep from the goats; 33 and He will put the sheep on His right, and the goats on the left.”
— The people that will be born during the Millennium Kingdom and become believers in Lord Jesus.

(I suppose that the saved, all the believers in the end of millenium  won't die. But will be transformed  with glorified bodies to live forever and forever in the New Heaven and the New Earth).

Who will die during and final Millennium time? People under God’s just judgment, the King of kings.
“All who will be born during that time will have to choose Jesus (be saved) just as before the Millennium. Those who don't accept Christ will be cursed with death. If they die during the Millennium, they will go to Hades to await the final judgment the second resurrection and the great white throne.”  The Other people will be rebelled anti God and Messiah and will be judged immediately)
("When the thousand years are completed, Satan will be released from his prison,  and will come out to deceive the nations which are in the four corners of the earth, Gog and Magog, to gather them together for the war..." Revelation 20:7-15)

Why all the believers in the end of millenium won't die?

Because Revelation 20:6 and Daniel 12:2  showed us two Resurrections the first  to the  righteous for everlasting life  before millenium and  is separeted for 1000-year to the  second resurrection that Will be to disgrace and everlasting  contempt.

(Reason that I suppose the saved in the end millenium won't die but will be transformed to live forever in the  new Heaven and the new Earth, with glorified bodies).

Who will be resurrected in the First Resurrection?

“Blessed and holy is the one who has a part in the first resurrection; over these the second death has no power, but they will be priests of God and of Christ and will reign with Him for a thousand years."

The First resurrection will occur before millenium to:

1. Those Saints-the dead in Christ (1 Thessalonians 4:13-18, 1 Corinthians 15:21) before seven-years of tribulation  or 70o Week of Daniel 9:27)
2. Those Saints-the dead before Church (O.T. Saints, who was named righteous since Adão, Abel, Seth and his descendants, ...  to John the Baptist, by exemplo)  their resurrection will be at the time of Second Coming of Lord Jesus  (When seven-years of tribulation is ending)

3.The same for Those Saints who were martyred during the Tribulation (Rev 7:9-14)  at the time of Second Coming of Lord Jesus, When seven-years of tribulation ending)

Conclusion
Here's how I understand it. The people who have become believers during the Millennium Kingdom won't die!

First resurrection will occur before millenium to
1. Those Saints-the dead in Christ
2. Those Saints-the dead before Church (OT who is righteous since Adão to John the Baptist, if  we can limited by exemplo)
3. Those who were martyred - the dead during the Tribulation Rev 7:9-14)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please take the [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and it also helps to check  out [how we are different than other sites](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites?s=2|0.7322) or our other [great FAQs about the site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

Answer (score 0):

When Adam and Eve were first created they were given bodies that were immortal.  Meaning that they would not die.  With the single act of sin in the garden, they put on mortality and as a result death entered into creation.  Death was foreign prior to the first sin.
Often we hear that the raptured will get glorified incorruptible bodies.  That is not what the Scripture tells us.  Paul tells us that the DEAD gets glorified incorruptible bodies.

1 Cor. 15:51-54  Behold, I shew you a mystery; We shall not all sleep, but we shall all be changed, In a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trump: for the trumpet shall sound, and the dead shall be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed.  For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality.  So when this corruptible shall have put on incorruption, and this mortal shall have put on immortality, then shall be brought to pass the saying that is written, Death is swallowed up in victory.

Look at the distinction that Paul makes… the DEAD get the glorified incorruptible bodies, while the raptured are merely changed.  The raptured get bodies just like Adam and Eve did prior to the fall, where they put on mortality with the single act of sin.

The significance of this in relation to the rapture is eye opening.  Firstly, if the raptured don’t get glorified incorruptible bodies, then they cannot be heaven bound.  Rather they meet Jesus in the air (1 Thess. 4) or clouds (Matt. 24:29-31).  Translated from one place on Earth to another.  At this point the raptured are forever with the Lord.  Jesus is not headed back to heaven in a giant u-turn as some suppose, but on His way to the Mount of Olives… Zech 14:4,5

Paul tells the Bride how to get ready on Earth for when Jesus comes for her with all of His saints…1 Thess. 3:10-13.  All of His saints refer to those who have died and risen first.  They are the ones that have been dwelling the the places in heaven that Jesus stated in John 14:2,3, “In my Father’s house are many mansions: if it were not so, I would have told you. I go to prepare a place for you.  And if I go and prepare a place for you, I will come again, and receive you unto myself; that where I am, there ye may be also.”  Jesus is going to be dwelling on Earth for the next 1000 years.  The tribulation saints who were martyred during the tribulation will be ruling and reigning with Him there…Rev. 20:4.   Jesus and His saints will not be returning to those dwelling places in heaven spoken of in John for 1000 years.  So you see, there is no need for the raptured to have glorified incorruptible bodies until then, because they are not heaven bound until the end of the millennium.

The word for rapture “harpazo” is used twice in the Word. Once in 1 Thess. 4 and the other in Acts where Philip was translated from the sea where he baptized the Ethiopian Eunuch.  Philip disappeared from one location and reappeared in another on Earth.  That is the definition of a rapture.  Often it is referred to as translated.  At the “rapture” or our gathering together with Him (2 Thess. 2:1), we are relocated from one place on Earth to another.  First the air/clouds, then to the Mount of Olives.

Satan is bound for 1000 years.  I do not know if sin is totally absent from the Earth at that time due to the selfishness of the flesh, but the tempter is not present until the end. It appears that sin is not totally absent from what Isaiah states… Is. 65:20  Obviously the choice to sin could “put on” mortality once again, if that were possible for the elect.  However, reproduction and having children is very possible for the elect, who do not have glorified bodies, but rather immortal bodies like Adam and Eve at the beginnings of creation.  Isaiah speaks of this form of immortality in Isaiah 65:20.

In Summary:  It is important to understand that without glorified bodies, residence in heaven doesn’t take place.  Only the dead get glorified bodies.  Without them the raptured remain on Earth with Christ for 1000 years.  Methuselah lived 969 years with a mortal body.  Longevity is the correct understanding of immortality that is spoken of by Paul.

Comment: You need to press enter twice to get proper line breaks! I went ahead and fixed that for you. That said, this is long and rambley. I can't see the relevant of most of it to the question. Maybe you could [edit] it to make it a bit more concise and precise?

Comment: @boldncourageous, you wrote, "When Adam and Eve were first created they were given bodies that were immortal."  Can you provide support for that, scriptural or otherwise?

Comment: @boldncourageous, You say Isaiah 65:20 shows people receiving immortal bodies again when the verse speaks of them dying.  Can you clarify how you arrive at v.20 showing immortality?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.  What does happen to the people who are born into the Millennial Reign and then die?  During this time there are those who are involved in the 1st resurrection present on the earth.  The 1st resurrection has subsections of groups who are resurrected after Christ.  First is the Bride of Christ.  Secondly are the Old Testament saints.  Thirdly are the ones who died in the Great tribulation.  All these are part of the 1st resurrection at the start of the Millennial reign.  The second resurrection has one occurrence at the end of the Millennial reign.  This includes everyone through history who did not believe and thus did not have righteousness credited to them.  So we are left with the ones who have mortal bodies yet believed on Christ in the Millennial reign.  The problem is they die and need resurrection bodies to continue in the New Heavens and New Earth.

It is my understanding that Rev20:5 answers the question.  Its subject is about the 1st resurrection, describing the Tribulation saints as blessed for being a part of it.  The 'rest of the dead' are those dying in the Millennial reign of Christ.   Rev 20:6 The second death has no power over them seems to include the dead of v5.  So in a nutshell, according to Rev 20:5 the millennial believers are resurrected at the end of the Millennial reign.  Useful?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer. Unfortunately the question itself is an older one that no longer fits the guidelines of the site. For your answer to work here, you would need to edit it to specify what church or denomination of Christians it represents, and ideally provide some references to church materials on the subject. See: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The premillennial view of the Christ's 1000 year reign has lots of different views.  Apocalyptic literature is highly symbolic where many items represent something else.  Reading apocalyptic literature too literally can lead to a lot of false renderings.

Isaiah 65:25

> "The wolf and the lamb shall feed together, and the lion shall eat straw like the bullock: and dust shall be the serpent's meat. They shall not hurt nor destroy in all my holy mountain, saith the Lord."

Some read this literally as God changing animal natures after the return of Christ.  Many times Isaiah uses parallelism, where additional verses/lines build onto and explain previous verses/lines.

> "Synonymous parallelism is a poetic literary device which involves the repetition of one idea in successive lines."
> https://www.gotquestions.org/synonymous-parallelism.html

The last half of that verse is, I believe, explaining the first half of that verse.  Not destroying nor hurting any more is a reference to peace on earth.  The millennium is free of the wars that had previously ravaged the planet, and neither lions eating straw or snakes eating dust is meant to be literal, but are metaphorical for peace on earth,

just like v.19 states,

> ". . . and the voice of weeping shall be no more heard in her, nor the voice of crying.

Is that literal, forever unable to cry, or is that symbolizing a time of joy.  V.16 states, ". . .the former troubles are forgotten. . . ."

A common biblical hermenuetic in dealing with prophecy is if the literal reading is not possible look for comparison or analogies and qualities a symbol might represent or what represents those qualities.
https://www.preceptaustin.org/the_key_inductive_study_pt2
https://bahaiteachings.org/what-do-the-wolf-and-the-lamb-symbolize/

If read literally the wolf feeding with the lamb and lions eating straw does not make sense.

The second half of Isaiah 65:25 interprets the first half.
See Principle #3: The Scripture Interprets Scripture Principle
https://goldcountrycalvary.com/images/pdf/HAClass7Principles.pdf

Is this question presupposing a lot of immortal people living on earth who will never die (I'm not sure)?  V.20 speaks of a child dying 100 years old.  This may forecast increased longevity, but also death.

This question is written from a pretrib rapture perspective, presupposing Christians saved after the rapture, thus living during the tribulation, are the only ones living on earth prior to Jesus' return who are allowed to inhabit the millennium with the raptured saints.  (I assume that's the perspective the asker is coming from).  You know posttrib adherents are also premillennialists.

I think the presuppositions behind the question are flawed.  Glorified bodies are what we get in eternity, yet the asker implies some have it and others don't while living side by side, asking if these others not raptured, living along side of these glorified saints, get it now or later.  Or what happens to those born during the millennium?  There is a lot of assumptions and the whole premise of these two classes of millennial inhabitants seems incongruent.

Glorification: The Eternal State of the Redeemed
https://www.gracegems.org/WINSLOW/Eternal%20Glorification.htm

Answer (score 0):

Jerusalem will be the capital of the earth in the millennium. Scripture says that if people don’t annually come to celebrate the feast of booths in Jerusalem no rain will fall on their home land. (Zech 14:16,17)

Isa 19:24 and Eze 38 seem to indicate that if anybody is going to fail this it will on average be people who live further away from Jerusalem, than people in the nearest vicinity like Egypt and Assyria.

With lack of rain follows drought, tiny harvests and starvation. Lack of food could make people even more selfish, and some could also take to theft, murder and cannibalism.

Not just people but also animals  would according to scripture be peaceful creatures on the holy mountain, Jerusalem (Isa 65:25). Further away from Jerusalem, however, animals and people would on average be increasingly carnal.

Scripture says that the one who gets hit by the curse and dies will do so first at the age of 100. (Isa 65:20)

This teaches us that drought will come upon people so gradually that they might not be able to understand what is going on until it is too late.

This will also explain why it is people at the periphery that will mount the fatal attack on Jerusalem in the last days. (Eze 38; Rev 20:8)

Consequently, in the millennium people who die a natural death do so due to their sin. Sin would have developed in these people because of rebellion to what God stands for of which the annual festivals of booths is  a yearly reminder and token of. People who don’t sin won’t die. (Eze 18:4,20)

The more godly people closer to Jerusalem (geographically or spiritually) could by the time "the day of the Lord" comes, through advances in technology, been about finished with their migration away from earth.

> By the same word the present heavens and earth are reserved for fire, being kept for the day of judgment and destruction of the ungodly.
> But the day of the Lord will come like a thief. The heavens will disappear with a roar; the elements will be destroyed by fire, and the earth and everything done in it will be laid bare. (2 Pet 3:7,10)